# Citation Explainination of Paragraph three under description

Tags: filing, citation

In reference to the patent: [US20140267936](https://www.google.com/patents/US20140267936)

Applicant mention a citation :-

> Another approach is disclosed in copending **U.S. application Ser. No.
>   ______, (Docket SPC0936PA)** filed on even date herewith

What does this citation mean?

Answer (score 0):

Cited reference is applicant another application which he does not know US application number. all he had a internal reference number.

to get cited patent you need to search in patent filed by applicant/ inventor within month, most likely it was filed earlier.

Present application internal reference number was **SPC0954PA**

[image: describe image]

do post a comment if you find that patent application to help someone having same question.